# Unable to remove read only property on click of a check box using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

In a table I have first element as checkbox and rest as textbox in every row. Initially I want to keep all text boxes readOnly and want to make them editable when corrosponding checkbox is clicked. Below is code I am using and its not working, please suggest.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:text').prop('readOnly',true);

    $('input:checkbox').on('click',function(){
        if($('this').prop('checked',true));
        {
            $('this').parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly',false);
        }

        else
        {
            $('this').parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly',true);
        }
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td id="A7x1_1"><input type="text"></td>
<td id="A7x2_1"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td id="A7x1_2"><input type="text"></td>
<td id="A7x2_2"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td id="A7x1_3"><input type="text"></td>
<td id="A7x2_3"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Combination of checkbox and text boxes is working for me however I want to make if there any pre checked check boxes, then text boxes corresponding to that should become non editable. for this I am using below code line but its not working for me.

```
if($('input:checkbox').prop('checked'))
    {
        $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly', false);
        $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this if statement you assigned the value for prop. that is the mistake

change

```
if ($(this).prop('checked' , true ))
```

to

```
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
```

script be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:text').prop('readOnly', true);

    $('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly', false);
        } else {
            $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using below code but its not working.

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('input:text').prop('readOnly',true);
 
 $('input:checkbox').on('click',function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked',true));
  {
   $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').removeProp('readOnly');
  }
  
  else
  {
   $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly',true);
  }
 });
 });

Comment: see the update answer the above code have same error

Comment: Instead of pasting the code into your comments and saying "its not working" - just tell us in what way it's not working, what's going wrong? What is it *not* doing that it should do, what is it doing that it should not?

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).prop('checked')` will return true or false

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:text').prop('readOnly', true);
    $('input:text').css('background-color', '#C0C0C0');
    $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly', false).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        }
    });
    $('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly', false).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly', true).val('').css('background-color', '#C0C0C0');
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d3Dhn/9/)

Comment: I am using the same way but it is not working for me
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('input:text').prop('readOnly',true);
 
 $('input:checkbox').on('click',function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked',true));
  {
   $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').removeProp('readOnly');
  }
  
  else
  {
   $(this).parent().nextAll().find('input').prop('readOnly',true);
  }
 });
 });

Comment: @user2866314 you posted code have errors,so kindly work with my above code

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally suggest the following approach:

```
// find all input elements whose type is equal to 'checkbox', bind a change
// event handler:
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    // move from the changed checkbox to the closest 'td' ancestor,
    $(this).closest('td')
    // select its sibling ('td') elements:
    .siblings()
    // find the 'input' elements:
    .find('input')
    // set the readonly property to false (if the checkbox is checked),
    // or to true, if the checkbox is not checked:
    .prop('readOnly', !this.checked);
// trigger the change-event-handler on page-load/DOMReady:
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8R324/).

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribut-equals-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Above code is working for me, the only additional thing I want is I want to check if there are any checkboxes already checked on page load. and dont want to make their corresponding text boxes readonly.

Comment: This should already do that, that's why we trigger the `change()` event, so that the page-load state of the checkboxes is assessed.